# Tomcat 6 to 7 Migration Realm error overrides final method init.()V

Tags: tomcat, configure

I'm trying to migrate an application from Apache Tomcat 5.5 to version 7. I migrated the application successfully from Tomcat 5.5.25 to Tomcat 6.0.41. I was then migrating the application from version 6.0.41 to version 7.0.28 and ran into an issue.  When I start up the Tomcat 7 server I receive the following error in the `catalina.out` log:

```
Jul 1, 2015 2:15:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /usr/local/opt/ldtools/share/java/apache-tomcat-7.0.28/conf/Catalina/localhost/ttste
st.xml
Jul 1, 2015 2:15:31 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement
SEVERE: Begin event threw error
java.lang.VerifyError: class com.att.csp.sca.tomcat.CSPRealm overrides final method init.()V
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:303)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1359)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2747)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processContextConfig(ContextConfig.java:612)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.contextConfig(ContextConfig.java:576)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:814)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:364)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:401)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1582)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I looked at the realm-howto.html page but it does seem to apply because when I read this in the Quick Start section:

> You only need to care about this if you are using a web application that includes one or more  elements, and a `<login-config>` element defining how users are required to authenticate themselves. If you are not utilizing these features, you can safely skip this document.

The application does not use `<login-config>` because it is commented out in the web.xml. Here is the Realm section in the `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/ttstest.xml` file looks like:

```
<code>
<Realm className="com.att.csp.sca.tomcat.CSPRealm">

    <Authenticator
        sysName="LD"
        validationEnv="PROD"
        loginURL="https://www.eaccess.xyz.com/empsvc/hrmgt/pagLogin"
        logoutURL="https://www.eaccess.xyz.com/empsvc/hrmgt/pagLogout"
        errorPage="authFailure.jsp">

        <Resource name="jdbc_tts">
            <Value
                type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
                debug="0"
                URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@devsrvr.pedc.xyz.com:1521:ttsdev"
                connectionCachingEnabled="true"
                connectionCacheName="my boring connection cache"
                user="test"
                password="test"
                connectionCacheProperties="{MinLimit=0, MaxLimit=2, InitialLimit=0}"
            />
        </Resource>

        <EventLogger
            type="com.att.csp.sca.log.DBEventLogger"
            dataSourceName="jdbc_tts"
            securityEventTableName="security_log"
            maxRequestURISize="255"
        />

        <RoleProvider
            type="com.att.csp.sca.DBRoleProvider"
            dataSourceName="jdbc_tts"
            userRoleTableName="user_role_matrix"
            userFieldName="user_id"
            roleFieldName="role"
            allowCaching="true"
        />

        <UserProfilePersistor
            type="com.att.csp.sca.DBUserProfilePersistor"
            dataSourceName="jdbc_tts"
            userTableName="users"
            userFieldName="id"
            lastActiveFieldName="last_active"
            lastIpAddrFieldName="last_ip_addr"
        />

    </Authenticator>
</Realm>
```

The jar files that work with the parameters in the CSPRealm are located in the `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` directory just like they were for the Tomcat 6 migration.